# wanem does not apply delay in both directions

Tags: linux, networking, emulation

I'm new here so please cut me some slack because i'm not very familiar with the procedures here :)

Anyway i have a LAN with three PCs' (A,B,C) A,C are some simple clients and B is a bridge with WANem on it, when i try to set delay time (100ms) to one of the cards that are connected to the machines A or C and try to ping each other. The result i get is assymetric.

i.e ping from A to B (without delay) 64 bytes from B : icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=13.9 ms

ping from A to B (with delay 100ms) 64 bytes from B : icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=113.9 ms When it should be 213.9ms!!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen this ?http://sourceforge.net/p/wanem/discussion/725629/thread/5346fe4d/#67d3

Comment: yes..but nobody answered on this post!i have almost the same problem!